# Bitbucket / git checkout specific folders when running pipeline

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm working with a set of applications stored in a git repository.  Some code is suitable for unit testing, but quite a bit of it isn't (yet).

I set up a bitbucket pipeline to build and test the unit-testable code.  That seems to work fine.

I would like to avoid checking out the remainder of the code.  Is there a way to check out only a subset of the branch?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to checkout specific files? or a specific commit?

Comment: Bob, I would like to checkout specific files, maybe specific directories.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a file -

```
git checkout branch_name file_name
```

Example:

```
git checkout master thenameofthefile.js
```

For a folder:

```
git checkout master -- dirname
```

EDIT:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
       - step:
           script:
            - ant deployCodeCheckOnly -Dsf.username=$SF_USERNAME Dsf.password=$SF_PASSWORD
             - git fetch
             - git checkout -b master -- dirname
```

Comment: Bob, thank you.  Is there a way to do that specifically with pipelines? My limited understanding  is that bitbucket automatically checks out the code, so I'm not sure how to control that.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use the script portion of the .yaml file?

Comment: Bob, I'm only familiar with the basics. Is there a way in the yaml script to control what is checked out?  Thanks.

Comment: Bob, I am checking into that today.   I'll report back when I have tried it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I only added the "- git fetch" line, but that is failing. Do I need to include a build.xml file and the "ant" line?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the failure code as an edit in your question above?

Comment: There was no failure code that I could see.  I'll try again tomorrow.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Bob, I didn't have git installed, so git fetch did not work.  I'm not sure I understand how that would prevent the pipeline from cloning the entire repository.  My original question was poorly worded.  Is there a way to avoid cloning the entire repository in the "build setup" step?  Thanks.

Comment: What the above is doing is cloning the entire repo, but immediately after cloning the entire repo we are adding out own custom step's via the scripts, which allows that step to use the specific checked out files/ directories that are required for your testing.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm trying to set the clone depth to 0 and then do manual checkouts (similar to what you're showing).  Hopefully that will work.  Thanks!

Comment: One last update.  git does not accept a depth value of 0 (only positive numbers) so at this point I am not able to override the cloning.  I think we'll have to live with cloning the entire repository.  Not ideal, but it works.   Thanks.

Comment: Well that stinks that it didn't let you do that, glad I could be of assistance! :)